# Filling in missing values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

Link: [CSV with missing Values](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bouncer-128fa.appspot.com/o/powergeneration.csv?alt=media&token=1d944f8f-dcae-4822-8094-93567d66131b)
[image]

I am trying to figure out the best way to fill in the 'region_cd' and 'model_cd' fields in my CSV file with Pandas. The 'RevenueProduced' field can tell you what the right value is for either missing fields. My idea is to make some query in my dataframe that looks for all the fields that have the same 'region_cd' and 'RevenueProduced' and make all the 'model_cd' match (vice versa for the missing 'region_cd').

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as r

#variables needed for ease of file access
url = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs3358/hw/hw2/'
file_1 = 'powergeneration.csv'



res = r.get(url + file_1)
res.status_code
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.text), delimiter=',')
```

There is likely many ways to solve this but I am just starting Pandas and I am stumped to say the least. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: its not clear what you are asking ... please include some of the csv in the question directly as well as the output you get vs what you expect

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the CSV. All combinations of 'region_cd' and 'model_cd' have the same 'RevenueProduced'

Comment: An example is RB and FG always have 11550 revenue

Comment: Link is now working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each `RevenueProduced` maps to exactly one `region_cd` and one `model_cd`.

Take a look at the `groupby` pandas function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

You could do the following:

```py
# create mask to grab only regions with values
mask = df['region_cd'].notna()

# group by region, collect the first `RevenueProduced` and reset the index
region_df = df[mask].groupby('RevenueProduced')["region_cd"].first().reset_index()

# checkout the built-in zip function to understand what's happening here
region_map = dict(zip(region_df.RevenueProduced, region_df.region_cd))

# store data in new column, although you could overwrite "region_cd"
df.loc[:, 'region_cd_NEW'] = df["RevenueProduced"].map(region_map)
```

You would do the exact same process with `model_cd`. I haven't run this code since at the time of writing this I don't have access to your csv, but I hope this helps.

Here is the documentation for `.map` series method. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

(Keep in mind a series is just a column in a dataframe)

Comment: Sorry, I just made some edits. I didn't apply a mask to prevent .first() from returning NaN for some mappings. And I also had a typo.